# Permutations (disjoint cycles)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am doing my revision just keep getting confused with these permutations
$(123)(143)(154)(34)$ on how to write them as disjoint cycles

I know you start from right to left 
at the rightmost brackets i.e. $1→1$ then $1→5$ $5→5$. 
I used Maple and Wolfram and answer is $25143$,
please help to see what I am missing.

Comment: but they are nog disjoint

Comment: They are *not* disjoint: consider in which cycles,say,  $3$ appears.

Answer (score 0):

You normally apply the permutations from left to right. So applying the cycle (123) to

1 2 3 4 5 $\ \ \ \ \ \ $we get

2 3 1 4 5 $\ \ \ \ \ \ $then (143) gives

2 1 4 3 5 $\ \ \ \ \ \ $then (154) gives

2 5 1 3 4 $\ \ \ \ \ \ $and finally (34) gives

2 5 1 4 3

So we could write the result in cycle form as (1253).

Comment: I would actually say it's more common (at least in beginner group theory courses) for permutations to act on the left, so that $\sigma \tau$ means "do $\tau$ first," probably the convention the OP is using and refers to.

Comment: @pjs36 Except that he appears to accept that the answer is 25143 and you do not get that if you use the other order.

Comment: Ah, I see. I interpreted their situation differently: I sensed confusion about why two different CAS were spitting out things that seemed to contradict their understanding (but they don't explicitly say what, if anything, *they* got instead).

Comment: @pjs36 
"I would actually say it's more common (at least in beginner group theory courses) for permutations to act on the left, so that στ means "do τ first,"...  
I think you meant, it's more common for permutations to act on the right .